Chain rule for $\frac{df(\mathbf xt)}{dt}$
I'm sorry, this is a really basic question...but AI and personal intuition (the only sources I unfortunately have) keep me answering in two different ways.
Let $\mathbf x \in \mathbb R^n$, $t \in \mathbb R$, $f: \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$. Does $$\frac{df(\mathbf xt)}{dt} = \frac{\partial f(\mathbf xt)}{\partial \mathbf x}\mathbf x$$ or $$\frac{df(\mathbf xt)}{dt} = \frac{\partial f(\mathbf xt)}{\partial (\mathbf xt)}\mathbf x$$?

What is $f$?  What kind of values does it take?

@Randall thank you, I've added the information

Isn't this a duplicate?

Please provide more context for your question and show what you have tried so far.

If $f_k$ denotes the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to its $k$th argument, then the chain rule says that
$$
\frac{d}{dt} f(t x_1, \dots, t x_n)
= \sum_{k=1}^n f_k(t x_1, \dots, t x_n) \, x_k
.
$$
Now if you prefer to write the partial derivatives as $\partial f/\partial x_k$ rather than $f_k$, and write $\partial f/\partial \mathbf{x}$ for the gradient, then this takes the vector form
$$
\frac{d}{dt} f(t \mathbf{x})
= \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}(t \mathbf{x}) \, x_k
= \frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{x}}(t \mathbf{x}) \, \mathbf{\cdot} \, \mathbf{x}
,
$$
where the dot denotes the standard inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$.
